# Chrome times out GET request fetching JS resource

Tags: google-chrome, http, vercel

We provide a JS snippet that downloads our SDK to customer websites (e.g. how GTM works).
We noticed that for a set number of users, that request times out. Note that this happens only for a subset of users and seemingly only on Chrome.

The request is supposed to hit a Vercel Serverless method cached on the edge. Note: the request doesn't seem to reach our servers meaning something is blocking it on the client side.

Initially, we thought chrome extensions were blocking the requests. However, after testing on incognito + separate MacBook (same connection), the timeout still occurred.

We ran `chrome://net-export` to dig into the logs but found nothing obvious. Obviously, something is blocking the request. We can't pinpoint what, though.. Further, we can't reproduce, so for us to test things out, we need to go through clients which is expensive.

Error in console: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
Req headers: `Provisional headers are shown`

```
t= 47031 [st=     0] +CORS_REQUEST  [dt=124433]
                      --> cors_preflight_policy = "consider_preflight"
                      --> headers = "sec-ch-ua: \"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\"\r\nOrigin: https://clientWebsite\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\nsec-ch-ua-platform: \"macOS\"\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n"
                      --> is_revalidating = false
                      --> method = "GET"
                      --> url = "https://ourServers/?queryParam=test"
t= 47031 [st=     0]    CHECK_CORS_PREFLIGHT_REQUIRED
                        --> preflight_required = false
t= 47031 [st=     0]   +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=124433]
                        --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                        --> traffic_annotation = 101845102
                        --> url = "https://ourServers/?queryParam=test"
t= 47032 [st=     1]      NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_URL_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t= 47032 [st=     1]     +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=124432]
                          --> initiator = "https://clientWebsite"
                          --> load_flags = 16448 (DO_NOT_SAVE_COOKIES | SUPPORT_ASYNC_REVALIDATION)
                          --> method = "GET"
                          --> network_isolation_key = "https://clientWebsite https://clientWebsite"
                          --> request_type = "other"
                          --> site_for_cookies = "SiteForCookies: {site=https://clientWebsite; schemefully_same=true}"
                          --> url = "https://ourServers/?queryParam=test"
t= 47032 [st=     1]        COMPUTED_PRIVACY_MODE
                            --> privacy_mode = "enabled"
t= 47032 [st=     1]        NETWORK_DELEGATE_BEFORE_START_TRANSACTION  [dt=0]
t= 47032 [st=     1]        HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t= 47032 [st=     1]        HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_OR_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                            --> result = "created"
t= 47032 [st=     1]        HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t= 47032 [st=     1]       +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=124432]
t= 47032 [st=     1]          HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                              --> source_dependency = 280583 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=171464 [st=124433]          HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                              --> source_dependency = 280584 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=171464 [st=124433]       -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=171464 [st=124433]     -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                          --> net_error = -118 (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
t=171464 [st=124433]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED  [dt=0]
t=171464 [st=124433] -CORS_REQUEST
t=171465 [st=124434] -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED
t=171465 [st=124434] -REQUEST_ALIVE
                      --> net_error = -118 (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
```

Comment: If these are desktops, it could be anti-malware, safe browsing, or other security software.  What happens if those PCs use Edge or Firefox instead?  Firefox is not Chromium so that rules out both extensions and chromium.  For both desktops and servers it could be LAN-based security.

Comment: yes, I'm thinking anti-malware or some firewall/dns block. Any idea how I can go about finding what's blocking the request? Ideally I'd have full access to the machine, but all communication is done directly with the customer...

Comment: Another possibility is the firewall  / DDoS / etc. security software on your end, for example if the clients are connecting from an IP address range that has been blocked for some reason.

Comment: Tests from firefox supposedly work 1/3 times, test from Safari always work. We have no blacklisted IP addr (unless vercel has under the hood). Given these are residential IPs i'd rule it out

Comment: "Any idea how I can go about finding what's blocking the request?" - you can start by suggesting Firefox to rule out Google Chrome and Chromium, other than that you just need to ask them.  On PC, if they are using non-Microsoft security software (Avast and such) it seems more likely that the "suite" might include that type of network interference.

Comment: They had tried on 2 different mac machines. One of them has an antivirus the other does not. On both machines, the request was blocked.